# главная библиотека с++

Tags: c++, библиотеки

Как называется библиотека подключающая все библиотеки в c++?

Comment: Да нет такой...

Comment: такая есть но я не помню как называется

Comment: думаю, что речь идет о stdafx.h

Comment: @KoVadim, это не библиотека, вообще.

Comment: Я знаю. Но этот хедер действительно может много чего подключить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*(Хотя я подозреваю, что ТС называет библиотекой header (.h) файл, включаемый директивой `#include`, отвечу формально, как если бы вопрос был в самом деле о библиотеках, т.е. файлах, откуда линкер при создании исполняемого модуля берет функции, прототипы которых описаны в тех самых headers)*

Библиотеки (ELF файл .so в *nix или .dll в windows), которая подключает все, конечно, не существует.

Наверное одной из основных C++ библиотек, подключаемой ко всем программам на этом языке является `libstdc++.so`.

Также можно заметить, что основная (в том же смысле) библиотека в системе, это `libc` -- именно там находятся все базовые функции, которые используют все функции всех библиотек всех языков (по крайней мере для вызова функций ОС, реализованных в ядре).

Answer (score 4):

Мне кажется, имелся в виду [`<bits/stdc++.h>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25311198/5812238)

Используется в олимпиадном программировании, чтобы не писать много `#include`-ов

Этот заголовок не является частью стандарта, поэтому работает только в g++, но не работает в Visual Studio